# SOX script to recognise special pattern

Tags: sox

Is it possible to define SOX script that would recognize a pattern having short broadcast followed by a very short pause and then again short broadcast? This would happen when someone presses tangent on radio transmitter twice shortly. I would use that as a trigger to run another script.

Another way, if above is impossible to reach, that transmit would last 2-4 sec followed by 1 sec silence.

EDIT:
Let me explain more about the project. Intention is to do ATIS (automated weather report) system for the aviation use. I have weather station and made script which create weather report to file. Then I will use festival program to speak it out to the airband with radio transmitter.

Channel is reserved for this usage and is without any other traffic, but I don't want to broadcast report endlessly because of power and heating issues.

So I need a trigger which would be 2 x tangent (transmit button) shortly. There would not be any speak on the channel, only the baseband (min rec level). And I don't want to record anything, only act as a trigger.

I wonder if sox is too slow to detect those short transmits and therefore mentioned other solution which might be easier to achieve? My idea was that when trigger is activated then sox will create file what I use as a another trigger for other stuff and then delete file afterwards. It could be also that some other program would suit better for this?

Comment: Searched a while for a way to do this. Here's all that I found that seemed rel: http://www.linuxplanet.org/blogs/?cat=813. There's also VAD/VOX (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection). Can you try and explain further your 2 ideas? I'm intrigued but would need more info or even some sample files regarding the tangent bit.